# About underscore.map

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the following object

```
{one : 1, two : 2, three : 3}
```

and I would like

```
[1,2]
```

Here my code

```
_.map({one : 1, two : 2, three : 3}, function(num, key){ 
         if (key==='one' || key==='two') {
             return num;
         } 
}); // [1, 2, undefined]
```

Actually I would like `[1,2]`

How can I improve my code?
thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You actually want to use [`_.pick`](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) and [`_.values`](http://underscorejs.org/#values):

```
_.values( _.pick( obj, "one", "two" ) )
```

Comment: It's worth reading the Underscore docs from start to end every few months. Tons of useful stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a built in possibility for that (e.g. in [scala](/questions/tagged/scala) you can use `flatMap` for that purpose). In [backbone.js](/questions/tagged/backbone.js) consider chained `map` and `filter`:

```
_({one : 1, two : 2, three : 3}).
  chain().
  map(function(num, key){ 
    if (key==='one' || key==='two') {
      return num;
    }
  }).
  filter(function(num) {
    return num !== undefined
  }).
  value();
```

UPDATE (per *@ZacharyK* comment): or use `reject` complementary to `filter`:

```
reject(function(num) {
  return num === undefined
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option to do this in two steps, first `map` then [`compact`](http://underscorejs.org/#compact)

Example:

```
myArray = _.map({one : 1, two : 2, three : 3}, function(num, key){ 
         if (key==='one' || key==='two') {
             return num;
         } 
    });

myArray = _.compact(myArray)
```

This solution works better for arrays than objects.

_.compact(array):

> Returns a copy of the array with all falsy values removed. In
>   JavaScript, false, null, 0, "", undefined and NaN are all falsy.

Comment: This is the one I used.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers will involve (at least) two loops through the length of the object. What you really want is `_.reduce`:

```
_.reduce({ one : 1, two : 2, three : 3 }, function ( out, num, key ) { 
    if ( key === 'one' || key === 'two' ) {
        out.push( num );
    }
    return out;
}, []);
// [1, 2]
```

That will give you your answer, compacted just as you like it, with just one loop through your object.

Answer (score 0):

Break it into two steps. First use a filter to select the values you want then use a map to get the values

```
_({..}).chain()
       .filter(function(num, key){
            return key ==='one'||key==='two';
        })
       map(function (num,key){
            return num;
       }).values()
```

Comment: You are missing a `.` between the `filter` method call and `map`. This will result in `map` being treated as a separate function, rather than as a method of the object being passed.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use:

```
_.map(['one','two'], function(key) { return obj[key]; });
```

which evaluates to `[1, 2]`

See (although due to the node repl I have to alias underscore to `__`):

```
> var __ = require('underscore');
> var obj = {one : 1, two : 2, three : 3};
> __.map(['one','two'], function(key) { return obj[key]; });
[ 1, 2 ]
```